# include and Get not working on index

Tags: php, include, get, root

I have a problem with my index.php, i have this small script that decides what content to deliver

```
        <?php $clase = $_GET['clase'];
if ($clase == empresa) {include ("empresa.php");}
elseif ($clase == productos) {include("productos.php");}
else {include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inicio.html"); }
?>
```

it works when i go to www.mysite.com/index.php

but when i go to www.mysite.com it doesnt and i cant just figure our why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set your server up to recognize default index's.

I use Apache and in the httpd.conf file you would want to change the `DirectoryIndex`.

Here is my copy:

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thx for the help, it was finally a problem in the httpd.conf. that didn't have index.php as the predetermined index.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around `empresa` and `productos`:

```
<?php $clase = $_GET['clase'];
if ($clase == 'empresa') {include ("empresa.php");}
elseif ($clase == 'productos') {include("productos.php");}
else {include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inicio.html"); }
?>
```

Comment: I was about to write that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check the include path on your server to ensure that include() can locate empresa.php and productos.php